# Дерево файлов. Воссоздание структуры на сервере в бд

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

При upload папок с помощью плагина https://github.com/malsup/form на сервер приходят файлы, полный путь к которым выглядит так (на стороне сервера получаю эту информацию с помощью HttpFileCollectionBase и FileInfo)

```
root/folder1/file1.txt
root/folder2/file2.txt
root/file3.txt
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно распарсить (примерный алгоритм или в какую сторону двигаться) эту информацию для корректного воссоздания структуры в базе данных

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Структура БД самая простая, это типичная иерархическая таблица каталогов:

```
Folder:
  ID
  ParentId
  ...
```

И файлы в каталоге:

```
File:
  ID
  FolderId 
  ...
```

В которой Folder ссылается сам на себя, а File ссылается на Folder.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как работать с подобной иерархической структурой можно почитать в интернете по теме иерархических данных в БД или Common table expression (CTE). К примеру можно немного взять отсюда:

http://club.shelek.ru/viewart.php?id=306

Разделив отдельно иерархическую структуру каталога и отдельно файлы, которые ссылаются на каталоги, вы сможете их хранить в БД с более-менее удобным способом обращения.

Для EntityFramefork это может выглядеть как-то так:

```
[Table("Folder")]
public class Folder
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Other { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ID")]
    public virtual Folder Parent { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual List<Folder> Children { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FolderId")]
    public virtual List<File> FilesInFolder { get; set; }
}

[Table("File")]
public class File
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int FolderId { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Byte[] Bytes { get; set; }
    public String Other { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FolderId")]
    public virtual Folder Folder { get; set; }
}

public class Entities : DbContext
{

    public Entities() : base("name=Entities") 
    {
        this.Database.Initialize(true);
    }

    public DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Folder> Folders { get; set; }

}
```

Пример заполнения данных:

```
        Entities entities = new Entities();

        Folder f1 = new Folder() { 
            Name = "SomeCatalog",
            Other = "Other",
            Children = new List<Folder>() { 
                new Folder() { 
                    Name = "SomeCatalog", 
                    Other = "Other", 
                    Children = new List<Folder>() 
                },
                new Folder() { 
                    Name = "SomeCatalogWFile", 
                    Other = "Other", 
                    Children = new List<Folder>() {
                        new Folder() { 
                            Name = "SomeCatalog", 
                            Other = "Other", 
                            Children = new List<Folder>() 
                        },
                        new Folder() { 
                            Name = "SomeCatalogWFileSub", 
                            Other = "Other", 
                            Children = new List<Folder>(),
                            FilesInFolder = new List<EntityModel.File>(){
                                new EntityModel.File() { Name = "File1", Other = "TXT" },
                                new EntityModel.File() { Name = "File1", Other = "TXT" }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    FilesInFolder = new List<EntityModel.File>(){
                        new EntityModel.File() { Name = "File1", Other = "TXT" },
                        new EntityModel.File() { Name = "File1", Other = "TXT" }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        entities.Folders.Add(f1);
        entities.SaveChanges();
```

В Вашем же случае Вам еще скорее всего надо проверять, существует ли каталог и есть ли в нем файлы для добавления. Это сложнее, но примерный код мог бы выглядеть так. Хотя данный далек от идеала, так как писался на коленке, но для примера думаю пойдет:

Промежуточный вспомогательный класс.

```
    class ParserPath
    {
        public Folder FolderPath { get; set; }
        public EntityModel.File FilePath { get; set; }
        public ParserPath(string path)
        {
            String[] PathRoad = Path.GetDirectoryName(path).Split('\\');

            FolderPath = new Folder() { Name = PathRoad[0], Other = "Other", Children = new List<Folder>() };

            Folder temp = FolderPath;
            for (int i = 1; i < PathRoad.Count(); i++)
            {
                Folder newTemp = new Folder { Name = PathRoad[i], Other = "Other", Children = new List<Folder>() };
                temp.Children.Add(newTemp);
                temp = newTemp;
            }

            FilePath = new EntityModel.File() { Name = Path.GetFileName(path), Other = "TXT" };

        }
    }
```

Сам парсинг:

```
        List<ParserPath> parserPathList = new List<ParserPath>()
        {
            new ParserPath("root/file1.txt"),
            new ParserPath("root/folder2/file2.txt"),
            new ParserPath("root/folder1/file1.txt"),
            new ParserPath("root/folder1/file3.txt"),
            new ParserPath("root/folder1/root/file3.txt"),
            new ParserPath("root/folder1/root/file4.txt"),
            new ParserPath("root/folder2/folder1/file2.txt")
        };

        //сохраняем структуру каталога
        foreach (ParserPath parserPath in parserPathList)
        {
            Folder current = entities.Folders.Select(p => p).Where(p => p.Name == parserPath.FolderPath.Name && p.ParentId == null).FirstOrDefault();
            if (current == null) 
            {
                entities.Folders.Add(parserPath.FolderPath);
            }
            else 
            {
                Folder root = parserPath.FolderPath;
                while (root.Children.FirstOrDefault() != null) 
                { 
                    Folder temp = current.Children.Select(p => p).Where(p => p.Name == root.Children.FirstOrDefault().Name).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (temp == null) 
                    {
                        current.Children.Add(root.Children.FirstOrDefault());
                        break;
                    }
                    root = root.Children.FirstOrDefault();
                    current = temp;
                }
            }
            entities.SaveChanges();
        }

        //предыдущий код изменяет коллекцию, что приводит к неправильным результатам.
        //Поэтому тут создается новая, что бы не переделывать код
        List<ParserPath> parserPathListCopy = new List<ParserPath>()
        {
            new ParserPath("root/file1.txt"),
            new ParserPath("root/folder2/file2.txt"),
            new ParserPath("root/folder1/file1.txt"),
            new ParserPath("root/folder1/file3.txt"),
            new ParserPath("root/folder1/root/file3.txt"),
            new ParserPath("root/folder1/root/file4.txt"),
            new ParserPath("root/folder2/folder1/file2.txt")
        };

        //сохраняем файлы из каталога
        foreach (ParserPath parserPath in parserPathListCopy) 
        {
            Folder current = entities.Folders.Select(p => p).Where(p => p.Name == parserPath.FolderPath.Name && p.ParentId == null).FirstOrDefault();
            Folder root = parserPath.FolderPath;
            while (root.Children.FirstOrDefault() != null)
            {
                Folder temp = current.Children.Select(p => p).Where(p => p.Name == root.Children.FirstOrDefault().Name).FirstOrDefault();
                root = root.Children.FirstOrDefault();
                current = temp;
            }
            if (current.FilesInFolder == null) current.FilesInFolder = new List<EntityModel.File>();
            current.FilesInFolder.Add(parserPath.FilePath);
        }
        entities.SaveChanges();
```

В итоге Вы должны получить примерно такую структуру в БД и при обычном SELECT из EF несложное обращение с данными:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сущность файл выглядит [так](https://github.com/AndiiAlbu/CloudStorage/blob/master/Cloud.Entities/Entities/AppCloudFileInfo.cs). Это может быть и файл и папка. То что так парсить можно я знаю, но не пойму как мне в точности сохранить структуру, т.е. root будет родителем для  folder1, folder2, file3.txt, folder1 будет родителем для file1.txt, folder2 будет родителем для file2.txt. Если пользователь захочет залить 100 файлов или больше.

Comment: возможно единственным нормальным способом будет сохранить все на сервере, а потом уже прочитать дерево каталогов

Comment: @AndriiAlbu, какую БД вы используете в своей работе(MSSQL/etc) и какую технологию для запросов(EF или чистый SQL)?

Comment: Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB, providerName="System.Data.SqlClient", технология Entity Framework

Comment: @AndriiAlbu, я обновил ответ, посмотрите, попробуйте разобраться. Хотя ответ вышел не совсем простым из-за объема и рассмотрения как БД, так и EF с примером кода парсинга.

Comment: спасибо за ответ и потраченное время